# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'A'

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, gensim

I am trying to perform tfidf on a matrix. I would like to use gensim, but `models.TfidfModel()` only works on a corpus and therefore returns a list of lists of varying lengths (I want a matrix).

The options are to somehow fill in the missing values of the list of lists, or just convert the corpus to a matrix

```
numpy_matrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2dense(corpus, num_terms=number_of_corpus_features)
```

Choosing the latter, I then try to convert this count matrix to a tf-idf weighted matrix:

```
def TFIDF(m):
    #import numpy
    WordsPerDoc = numpy.sum(m, axis=0)
    DocsPerWord = numpy.sum(numpy.asarray(m > 0, 'i'), axis=1)
    rows, cols = m.shape
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            amatrix[i,j] = (amatrix[i,j] / WordsPerDoc[j]) * log(float(cols) /     DocsPerWord[i])
```

But, I get the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'A'`

I copied the function above from another script. It was:

```
def TFIDF(self):
    WordsPerDoc = sum(self.A, axis=0)        
    DocsPerWord = sum(asarray(self.A > 0, 'i'), axis=1)
    rows, cols = self.A.shape
    for i in range(rows):
       for j in range(cols):
          self.A[i,j] = (self.A[i,j] / WordsPerDoc[j]) * log(float(cols) / DocsPerWord[i])
```

Which I believe is where it's getting the `A` from. However, I re-imported the function.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show the *complete* traceback (i.e. the entire error message).  That should show which line is triggering the error.

Comment: `.A` is a `np matrix` adttribute, turning it into an array.  Try omitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.A` is either an `np.matrix` or `sparse` matrix.  For both `A` means, return a copy that is a `np.ndarray`.  In other words, it converts the 2d matrix to a regular numpy array.  If `self` is already an array, it would produce your error.

It looks like you have corrected that with your own version of `TFIDF` - except that uses 2 variables, `m` and `amatrix` instead of `self.A`.

I think you need to look more at the error message and stack, to identify where that `.A` is.  Also make sure you understand where the code expects a matrix, especially a sparse one.  And whether your own code differs in that regard.

I recall from other SO questions that one of the learning packages had switched to using sparse matrices, and that required adding `.todense()` to some of their code (which expected dense ones).